# Change the drupal 8 folder with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-8

So I have installed and got a site at

`example.com/sites/prod`

and want users to go to

`example.com/`

to see the site. I have a `.htaccess` file that does the trick, along with the `trusted hosts` installed, but I have hit a problem where if I go to

`example.com/user`

I hit the following message

> Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.

I assume it is an new feature from drupal 8 as I had successfully done this in 7.

The error also occurs if you submit a contact form.

I have tried googling around but I am getting confused.

Comment: Out of my curiosity : if you want users to go to example.com, why don't simply  create a proper WHATEVERYOUWANT/sites/example.com directory?

Comment: Do you mean leave my Drupal installation at example.com/sites/prod but inside that folder create 'sites/example.com'? Will that fix my problems - basically I have a dev and production site in that sites folder - each containing separate installations-  the dev is accessed via a sub domain 'dev.example.com' but shared hosting means I can't change example.com to point to the prod folder

Comment: Ok. So, I suggest you to use sites/devel.example.com for development and  and sites/example.com for production. This way, you are following Drupal design per  multidomain setting, and it will work. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

My use case was one where the Drupal install, only used for backend (fully decoupled), could not "live" in the root. As for your case I used the *.htaccess* file to define a series of redirects and ran into the problem that for example *../backend/node/26/edit?destination=/backend/admin/content* would result in the error you mention after form save.

Adding the below to the *settings.php* solved the problem:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^example\.com$',
  '^www\.example\.com$',
  '^localhost$',
);
```

Obviously change the URL with your own.